# Effective algorithm for homework issue

Tags: java, data-structures

I need to analyze a text that fulfils the following problem:

> Generate an output that shows a count of how many times each word occurs in the text. The report should be sorted first by word length, followed a natural sort.

I was docked points for my solution given below. Is there a better solution available? I have not used maps or any collection because we were told that extra credit will be due for those who don't use collections.

My POJO

```
/**
 * An instance of this object represents the string that occurs in a sentence
 * and the number of times it occurs in a single string.
 */
public class Word implements Comparable<Word> {
  private final String word;
  private int counter = 1;

  public Word(String word) {
    this.word = word;
  }

  public void incrementCounter() {
   this.counter ++;
  }

  public String getWord() {
    return word;
  }

  public int getCounter() {
    return counter;
  }

  /**
   * Overrides the default hashcode function.
   */
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int hashCode = 103034;
    hashCode += this.word != null ? this.word.hashCode() ^ 3 : 0;
    hashCode += this.counter ^ 2;
    return hashCode;
  }

 /**
  * Overrides the default equals function. 
  */
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   if (obj == null) {
     return false;
   }
   if (this == obj) {
     return true;
   }
   if (!(obj instanceof Word)) {
     return false;
   }
   Word otherWord = (Word) obj;
   if (this.word != null && this.word.equals(otherWord.getWord())) {
     return true;
   }
   return false;
 }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Word");
    sb.append("{word='").append(word).append('\'');
    sb.append(", counter=").append(counter);
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
  }


/**
 * The implementation checks for the order of comparison.
 * The implementation first compares by presence of word string.
 *
 * @param w Word to be compared
 * @return calculated order of comparison.
 */
@Override
public int compareTo(Word w) {
  if (w == null) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (this.word == null && w.getWord() != null) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (this.word != null && w.getWord() == null) {
    return -1;
  }
  return StringUtils.compareString(this.word, w.getWord());
 } 
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * An instance of this class is responsible for comparing the instances of two word 
 * instances by comparing against the word string.
 */
public class WordComparator implements Comparator<Word> {

  /**
   * Compares two instances of words first by length of the word string and then by the
   * word itself.
   *
   * @param firstWord first word to be compared
   * @param secondWord second word to be compared
   * @return negative number if the first word is less than the second word;
   *     positive if the first word is greater than the second word; 0 if equal.
   */
   @Override
   public int compare(Word firstWord, Word secondWord) {
     if (firstWord == secondWord) {
       return 0;
     }
     if (firstWord != null && secondWord == null) {
       return -1;
     }
     if (firstWord == null && secondWord != null) {
       return 1;
     }
     return StringUtils.compareString(firstWord.getWord(), secondWord.getWord());
    }
}
```

---

Utility class.

```
public class StringUtils {

  // Not to be instantiated.
  private StringUtils() {}

  /**
   * Compares the string first by word length and then by string.
   *
   * @param first First string to be compared.
   * @param second Second string to be compared
   * @return integer representing the output of comparison.
   */
   public static int compareString(String first, String second) {
     if (first == second) {
       return 0;
     }
     if (first == null && second != null) {
        return 1;
     }
     if (first != null && second == null) {
       return -1;
     }
     int wordLengthDifference = first.length() - second.length();
     if (wordLengthDifference == 0) {
       return first.compareTo(second);
     }
     return wordLengthDifference;
  }
}
```

---

Main method:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

/**
 * Finds the number of occurrences of word a in given string. The implementation expects
 * the input to be passed adsingle string argument.
 */
 public class StringWordOccurences {

  /**
   * Finds the number of occurrences of a word in a string. The implementation relies
   * on the following assumptions.
   *
   * <p>The word is passed as separate strings as in {@code "Hello" "World"} instead of 
   * a single string  {@code "Hello World"}.
   *
   * @param args Arguments to be sorted by first word length and then by string.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args == null || args.length == 0) {
      System.out.println("There were no words. The count is 0");
      return;
    }

    // Find the number of unique words and put them in an array.
    Comparator<Word> wordComparator = new WordComparator();
    Arrays.sort(args, new Comparator<String>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(String first, String second) {
         return StringUtils.compareString(first, second);
      }
    });

    Word [] words = new Word[args.length];
    int numberOfUniqueWords = 0;
    for (String wordAsString : args) {
      Word word = new Word(wordAsString);
      int index = Arrays.binarySearch(words, word, wordComparator);
      if (index > -1) {
        words[index].incrementCounter();
      } else {
        words[numberOfUniqueWords ++] = word;
      }
     }
     Word [] filteredWords = Arrays.copyOf(words, numberOfUniqueWords);
     // The display output.
     for (Word word : filteredWords) {
       System.out.println(word);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know why you were docked points?

Comment: @nattyddubbs Unfortunately not.

Comment: well, you did import java.util.Collections even though you didn't use it...

Comment: I think this should go on coderview not stackoverflow.
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions.

Comment: I did not know about codereview.stackexchange. Should I move this question there or should I keep it here for now?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the binary searches after you have sorted your words in the desired order, because the identical words will be next to each other. Just go over all the words and compare each with the previous one. If they are equal, increment the counter. If they are not equal, you can print the results for the finished previous word right away (no need to store the results in an array). You also don't really need the Word class, you can do it with Strings.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I implemented it your way and it works. Too late the assignment has already passed.

The snippet is here: https://gist.github.com/krishnanand/5001372

Comment: @Kartik But it is not too late to accept/upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

A few points I can think of but obviously these are second guesses...

1. You have 3 places where there is similar logic for doing the Word compare.
2. Ditch the Arrays.sort, Arrays.binarySearch and Arrays.copyOf. Do the searching yourself - might be simpler
3. You could actually sort after you have reduced to unique values